# how to solve the differential equation : $\frac{d^2{y}}{dx^{2}} = \frac{1}{y^3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As I am a beginner in Differential equations, I have no idea how to solve the following differential equation :
$$\frac{d^2{y}}{dx^{2}} = \frac{1}{y^3}$$

Thanks in advance for helping solving the DE.

Comment: Try to multiply by $\frac{dy}{dx}$ : both sides become the derivative of known expressions.

Comment: Try to derivate $(y^\prime) ^2 + y^{-2}$.

Comment: yes, it reduces to ${(\frac{dy}{dx})}^2 = - \frac{1}{y^2} +c$. Now how to proceed?

Comment: Separate the variables.

Comment: @Martin "Separate the variables" Can you be any more specific? Or did you miss that the LHS is $y''$, not $y'$?

Comment: No - Dr. Sonnhard Graubner already did it. Phil Jones already reduced the problem to $y'^2=-y^{-2} +c $ which is separable - and Phil Jones asked how to proceed, so I think my comment was a decent clue. But it seems I needed to be more specific, and I'll keep that in mind in future comments.

Answer (score 2):

multiplying by $y'$ and integrate we have $$\frac{1}{2}(y')^2=C_1-\frac{1}{2y^2}$$
$$\int\frac{y'}{\sqrt{2C_1-\frac{1}{y^2}}}=\pm\int 1dx$$
so we get
$$\frac{\sqrt{2C_1-\frac{1}{y^2}}y}{2C_1}=C_2\pm x$$

Comment: It would be easier to multiply the first equation with $8y^2$ and set $v=y^2$ to get $v'^2=Cv-4$. The corresponding expressions of the next equations are slightly more simple.

Answer (score 2):

Let's solve for $f=y^2$.

The equation $$y^3y''=1$$

becomes $2ff''=2y^2(2y'^2+2yy'')=4y^2y'^2+4y^3y''=f'^2+4$

So $f$ is solution of $$2ff''-(f')^2=4\tag{E}$$

If we derivate this : $\require{cancel}\cancel{2f'f''}+2ff'''-\cancel{2f'f''}=0$

Since the original equation $y''=\dfrac 1{y^3}$ require that $y$ does not annulate (and so shouldn't $f$) then we conclude that $f'''=0$.

Thus $f=ax^2+bx+c$ and when we report in $(E)$ we find that $4ac-b^2=4$

> Finally $y=\pm\sqrt{ax^2+bx+\dfrac{b^2+4}{4a}}$ with $a>0$

*Note that $\Delta=b^2-4ac=-4<0$ and $a>0$ so the internals of the square root is positive.*

Comment: You can make the last remark more explicit by writing the solution as $$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{(2ax+b)^2+4}{4a}}.$$

Comment: @LutzL Indeed, I just didn't think about it.